# Interface Orientation Rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I'm developing a code in which the initial view controller is `landscape` view. When a button in that view controller is pressed then the next view controller should be `portrait`. My `root view controller` is a `navigation controller`.

This is a story board application.

I returned Yes for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` in the first root view controller and
`UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` for second view controller. But the rotation does  not work at first. We have to rotate the view to change it to correct rotation.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here one way to change orientation of device is ...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

}
```

here in which class you want to change the orientation then write the line in your `viewWillAppear:` method

and also for remove the warning of UIDevice just declare bellow code in your .m file

```
@interface UIDevice (MyPrivateNameThatAppleWouldNeverUseGoesHere)
- (void) setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;
@end
```

here this code define above the @implementation file
hope this help you...

:)

Comment: Sorry! but that shows error.


 
The error is
Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'UIDevice' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'setOrientation:'

Comment: Thanks Paras Joshi that was really awesome the code worked like a charm.... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

When your second `ViewController` gets loaded, add this line either in the `viewDidLoad` or in the orientation change event receiving method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

EDIT:

Ok then update your method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, in the CiewController which you want to show in portrait, like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

And also make sure that in the nib file, you have the orientation set to `Portrait` in the Attribute Inspector.

It will do the job for you.

Comment: I added this the device get rotated but the view controller doesnt rotate :(

Comment: Did you check your nib file for the orientation?

Comment: Its done Kanan, Parsi's code worked. Thanks for your support and time.